# Почему цикл не останавливается?

Tags: pascal, циклы

При запуске в консоль выводятся значения g, каждый раз с увеличенной sigma на 0.1. С каждым разом g уменьшается пока не доходит до нуля (чем больше sigma, тем меньше g). В итоге, дойдя до нуля цикл не останавливается, хотя условие выполнения цикла - пока g>1. Что я делаю не так?

```
var g,sigma:real;
x,i:integer;
 begin

  x:=100;
  sigma:=0;

   repeat
   sigma:=sigma+0.1;
   g:=1/(2.506628275*sigma)*power(2.718281828,(-1*sqr(x))/(2*sqr(sigma)));
   g:=roundto(g,-4);
   writeln(g:10,4);  //g перестаёт изменятся дойдя до значения 0.0E+00004 , что, как 
   until g>1;        //я понимаю, больше 1. Но цикл продолжается, хотя значение  
                     //остаётся
 readln;
 end.
```

Comment: 0.0E+00004 > 1 - все правильно?

Comment: А что это значит?

Comment: да я просто думаю, что твое условие некогда не выполняется

Comment: Не силён в паскале, скажите power и roundto - это стандартные функции или Ваши? Просто ideone ругается на них [http://ideone.com/Yl2CS][1]


  [1]: http://ideone.com/Yl2CS

Comment: Это стандартные ф-ии. Но писал я в Delphi. Там они объявлены в модуле Math

Comment: Объясните пжл что значит 0.0E+00004 ?

Comment: ну ты же сам все написал.... я тебе сразу правильный ответ дал. Вот твой комментарий - g перестаёт изменятся дойдя до значения 0.0E+00004, вот я тебе и показал, что 1 больше, отсюда условие не выполняется. Вроде бы так, если я не ошибся. :)

Comment: Не ошибся, у ОПа с <a href="http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282.506628275*x%29*power%282.718281828%2C%28-1*sqr%28100%29%29%2F%282*sqr%28x%29%29%29">матаном</a> еще хуже чем c форматированием. [тупой маркдаун портит ссылку](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/%282.506628275*x%29*power%282.718281828%2C%28-1*sqr%28100%29%29/%282*sqr%28x%29%29%29)

Comment: так тут считать не обязательно все и так прикинув на глаз формулу, видно что меньше 1 =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот щас тупо взял в `Ехеl` переложил формулу и как я понял у вас `g` всегда < 1

Comment: мда... Ок, извините, видимо ошибка моя. Буду переделывать.

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте поменять `var g,sigma:real;` на `var g,sigma:double;`. Но точно не уверен.

Comment: Не сработало(

Comment: Посмотри еще функцию округления g:=roundto(g,-4); Она же округляет до целого числа?

Comment: Нет. Здесь я хотел округлить g до 4-ёх знаков после запятой

Comment: Попробуй программу без roundto. Интересно, как сработает.